# Is this function similar to a constructor?

Tags: javascript, function, constructor

```
function catRecord(name, birthdate, mother) {
  return {name: name, birth: birthdate, mother: mother};
}
```

My understanding of a constructor is a function is used to build up the object.

Would this catRecord function count as a constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the function you've given returns a new associative array with no type information. The constructor you're after is something like this:

```
function fixedCatRecord(name, birthdate, mother) {
    this.name = name;
    this.birthdate = birthdate;
    this.mother = mother;
}
```

This way, you'll have an object that knows it's a fixedCatRecord, which means it has access to all the appropriate metadata (such as knowing what methods you can call on it).

Mind you, both of them CAN be used with "new", but it will be an object of type Object (which is the default for an associative array), *not* an object of type catRecord.

e.g., if you're using something (like Chrome) where console.log gives type information:

```
// this is an Object, not what you want!
console.log(new catRecord("Fluffy", "12/12/12", "Melody"));
// this is a fixedCatRecord, good!
console.log(new fixedCatRecord("Fluffy", "12/12/12", "Melody"));
```

Answer (score 1):

> Would this catRecord function count as a constructor?

Nope.

It's very similar to a constructor, yes, but I wouldn't call all functions/methods that return an object "[constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_%28object-oriented_programming%29)". I use the term [**factory**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28software_concept%29) instead when no inheritance is involved.

The EcmaScript specification defines a [constructor](http://es5.github.io/#x4.3.4) simply as a

> Function object that creates and initialises objects.

though there's already a note on prototypical inheritance right below it. And in the [language overview](http://es5.github.io/#x4.2.1) it says

> A constructor is a function that has a property named “`prototype`” that is used to implement *prototype-based inheritance* and *shared properties*.

So while technically every object that [implements](http://es5.github.io/#x13.2.2) `[[construct]]` is a constructor, in JavaScript the term "constructor" is used only for functions that are intended to be used with the [`new` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) and create instances which share a common `prototype` (forming a "class"). Conventionally, their names are capitalized then.

Answer (score 0):

> Constructor is a function that is called automatically whenever we
>   create an instance of class .

Returns a reference to the Object function that created the instance's prototype. Note that the value of this property is a reference to the function itself, not a string containing the function's name, but it isn't read only (except for primitive Boolean, Number or String values: 1, true, "read-only").

If we will create an instance of `Date` class then:

```
var e = new Date();
alert(e.constructor); //return Date
```

Then its constructor will return `Date` that will be the name of constructor of the **Date** class.

Similarly if we will create the instance of Number like `var n = new Number(5);` then its constructor will return the Number which will the name of constructor.

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_constructor_boolean.asp).

**Example:**

```
var Vehicle = function Vehicle() {
  // ...
}

var vehicle = new Vehicle();
```

WHAT HAPPENS WHEN A CONSTRUCTOR IS CALLED?
When `new Vehicle()` is called, JavaScript does four things:

1. It creates a new object.
2. It sets the constructor property of the object to Vehicle.
3. It sets up the object to delegate to Vehicle.prototype.
4. It calls Vehicle() in the context of the new object.

Comment: Check [EcmaScript §13.2.2](http://es5.github.io/#x13.2.2) - there is no `constructor` property involved when calling `new`

Comment: @Bergi OP wants to know the constructor in javascript not in ECMAscript. and nowhere is written that which you are saying.

Comment: javascript *is* EcmaScript. If you care about JavaScript, then refer to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new#Description). However, my point was that your second bullet is wrong, JS does only do three things.

Comment: @Bergi in the second points, my means is that when we create the object of class by `new`  then it call the constructor.

Comment: Yes, but no `.constructor` property is created!

Answer (score -1):

```
function Employee()  // Class and constructor
{ 
  this.name = "A";
  this.age = "23";
}

var a = new Employee(); // Creating instance

alert(a.name); // alerts A

function Employee(a,b)  // Class and constructor
{ 
  this.name = a;
  this.age = b;
}

var one = new Employee("A",23); // Creating instance
var two = new Employee("B",25); // Creating instance

alert(two.name); // alerts B
```

Hope the above example explains you everything you need

**Additional :**

If you want to add a method to the class `Employee` , you should do it using `prototype`

```
Employee.prototype.printName = function()
{
   document.write(this.name);
};

two.printName();  // Writes B
```